# Gets exceptions ""at least one object must implement icomparable"" only when apply method ToList() to IQueryable<>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

When i don't use ToList() method to query firsQue  everything is "Ok!" but i need execute firsQue  immediately!  Then i added to the end ToList() method and got exception in second query secQue "at least one object must implement IComparable".

---

I dont understand that caused it, grouping   performs  by  g.Action.ActionType.Name... It's string, string type implements IComparer interface

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var firsQue  = GetAll()
        .SelectMany(s => s.Goals
            .Where(s2 => s2.ID == 2)
             .SelectMany(f => f.Actions
                 .SelectMany(h => h.GoalProgresses))).ToList();


    var secQue = (from g in firsQue  
                        group g by g.Action.ActionType.Name into a
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = a.Key,
                            Duration = a.Sum(s => s.Action.Duration),
                            Done = a.Sum(s => s.DurationComplete),
                            RemainsToDo = (a.Sum(s => s.Action.Duration) - a.Sum(s => s.DurationComplete))
                        })
                         .OrderBy(s => s)
                         .ToList();

    System.Console.ReadLine();
}

static IQueryable<Patient> GetAll()
{
    return db.Patients;
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList` on the first query?  That forces all of the operations in the second query to be performed by the application in memory instead of within the database.

Comment: Cause list that i got by firsQue will used many times with subsequent linq operators that will provide many various data sets. Hence i don't want to twitch database everytime

Comment: LINQ queries defer execution.  Defining the query doesn't execute it, it merely describes how one might get the data.  The fact that you further refine it to get different queries later is a sign that you probably shouldn't be materializing the query.

Comment: "-LINQ queries defer execution"  - i know . And that why i use ToList().
"- The fact that you further refine it to get different queries later is a sign that you probably shouldn't be materializing the query" - i want to improve performance. What better fetch data from database one time with firsQue. And work with this data stored in heap via addition LINQ syntax. Or better fetching many times the same data

Comment: *Or better fetching many times the same data via firsQue  as part of every completed, refined big query

Comment: It's probable that performing several smaller and more efficient queries of the DB will work better than pulling back all of the data and doing a *lot* of further filtering on the application side.

Comment: Probably you are right. I work on MVC application and everytime when  starting debug, automaticaly recreates new database. It's needed cause i fill everytime database with random data. I am begginer in MVC perhaps i  mistake somewhere. Tomorrow i will test performance with this  two ways. And write down to you. Thanks for help !

Comment: Do you know why it worked with .OrderBy(s => s) without ToList() method  ?

Comment: It didn't work, it just wasn't throwing an exception because you were never executing the query.

Comment: secQue ended by ToList() method and it work with .OrderBy(s => s) and only then firsQue dont have ToList()...  all works believe me )) you can test this coe by self and you see

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.OrderBy(s => s)
```

Compiler doesn't know how to compare your values and perform the ordering.Your type must implement `IComparable` (though it's anonymous type) or you can make your sort by some property:

```
.OrderBy(s => s.ID)
```

Comment: Yes, it helped, and it logical.  But that if i dont need to change order and need to use Skip(), Take() extention methods ? And the main question still exist, why it query work with  .OrderBy(s => s) when i dont use ToList() at first query firsQue

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `OrderBy` but your expression `s => s` is just yielding the anonymous type created in the `select new` above. Anonymous types are not comparable, so you can't order by them. Maybe you mean `.OrderBy(s => s.Name)`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `OrderBy` with your expression like `c => c.someParameter`   and if your some parameter is reference parameter of other table then also you will get same error like e.g.

```
var sortedOrders = allOrders.OrderBy(s =>s.Branch);
```

In above example all orders is collection of orders and I want to sort then on branch.  But branch is reference column of Branch Table. So I was getting error.

Hence if you are ordering by using reference column then you should do in following way.

```
var sortedOrders = allOrders.OrderBy(s =>s.Branch.Id)
```

or any parameter form branch column like branch name etc.